# Music from the movies ♬ ♬

Tags: cipher, movies, music

The following six audio samples represent, perhaps, the best-known classical music compositions as they have been used in more than 150 mainstream movies.

**This question asks you to identify the six original composers.**

Unfortunately, the last audio sample has been transmogrified (messed up) **beyond recognition**.  You can still identify the sixth composer by either:

- un-transmogrification of the sixth audio sample or
- decoding this cipher using the **surnames** of the first five composers:

  ```
  5-5, 2-6, 3-3, 1-4, 4-1, 2-1, 5-2, 1-3, C, 5-1, 3-4, 1-5, 2-1, B, 3-5, 3-6, 4-2, 4-6, 2-5
  ```

**Here are the audio samples** (each is 150 kB or less):  **[1.ogg](https://googledrive.com/host/0B5qtVpyoZk81fk1IV3ctMmliU1pOSWtqY1FNNUFLS01RdWRtNVA0enFvRkVnVWJMT3NFME0/1.ogg), [2.ogg](https://googledrive.com/host/0B5qtVpyoZk81fk1IV3ctMmliU1pOSWtqY1FNNUFLS01RdWRtNVA0enFvRkVnVWJMT3NFME0/2.ogg), [3.ogg](https://googledrive.com/host/0B5qtVpyoZk81fk1IV3ctMmliU1pOSWtqY1FNNUFLS01RdWRtNVA0enFvRkVnVWJMT3NFME0/3.ogg), [4.ogg](https://googledrive.com/host/0B5qtVpyoZk81fk1IV3ctMmliU1pOSWtqY1FNNUFLS01RdWRtNVA0enFvRkVnVWJMT3NFME0/4.ogg), [5.ogg](https://googledrive.com/host/0B5qtVpyoZk81fk1IV3ctMmliU1pOSWtqY1FNNUFLS01RdWRtNVA0enFvRkVnVWJMT3NFME0/5.ogg), [6.ogg](https://googledrive.com/host/0B5qtVpyoZk81fk1IV3ctMmliU1pOSWtqY1FNNUFLS01RdWRtNVA0enFvRkVnVWJMT3NFME0/6.ogg).** Some minor audio adjustments have been made to defeat Shazam.

**EDIT** - here is an alternate method to receive the audio samples:

1. Download the following image
2. Change its file extension from .gif to .rar
3. Extract the six audio files using WinRAR (other unzip software may not work)

[image: embedded audio files]
<sub>These audio samples are from **public domain** sources on either Musopen or Wikipedia.  The compositions and the performances are both free from copyright.</sub>

Comment: Amazing question!

Comment: I get a 404 for 5.ogg

Comment: @TobiaTesan - Thanks for letting me know.  I don't see a problem with googledrive but later today I will try to embed the audio files into a picture and upload to imgur as well.

Comment: 404 error for all musics...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So far:

Second:

> Felix Mendelssohn's "Wedding March"

Fourth:

> Gioachino Rossini's "William Tell Overture"

Fifth:

> George Frideric Handel's "Hallelujah from the Messiah"

Through the collective effort of [BmyGuest](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5840/bmyguest) and [pacoverflow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4450/pacoverflow) and their answers [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/16778/5610) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/16780/5610) we get:

> Johann Strauss II
> Felix Mendelssohn
> Richard Wagner
> Gioachino Rossini
> George Frideric Handel

Decoding (first index is the composer, second the letter in the surname), results in:

> elgarmarchnumberone -> Elgar's March Number One -> Elgar's March No. 1

The sixth composer being:

> Sir Edward William Elgar

Comment: Ok,  I wanted to try out a puzzle with audio clues but I guess that was too easy. ;-)

Comment: @Len I am sort of a music freak, the question was in fact amazing. Keep up the great work!

Comment: @Len Also you've made my day as I now can't stop listening the sixth one :)

Comment: @Len Wouldn't have thought that I *ever* post on a music puzzle as first. I'm quite *not* a music expert or even listening to music very much - and I'm *really* bad at trivia & names ;c)

Comment: @BmyGuest - You did well then! I'm still puzzling with The pyramid code...

Answer (score 5):

**Work in progress**

First

> Blue Danube waltz, Johann Strauss II

Second

> Wedding March, Richard Wagner

Third

> Klaviersonate op. 35, Frédéric Chopin

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

3.ogg

> Bridal Chorus by Richard Wagner